# How to Configure Capistrano to Deploy from Local Git Repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

What changes do I need to make to the `deploy.rb` file below to make it deploy my app from a local git repo? If I can't deploy from a local repo, can I have capistrano use the working copying instead?

```
set :application, "my_app"
set :repository, "."
set :local_repository, "file:///path/to/application/.git"
set :deploy_to, "/data/www/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :copy_cache, true
set :user, "dane"
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, :git # Should I change this to :none
set :branch, "master"
```

Answer (score 57):

That's easy:

```
set :scm, :none
set :repository, "."
set :deploy_via, :copy
```

Simply run Capistrano from the root of your project.

Comment: +1. But, in capistrano v 2.12.0 I also had to do `set :local_repository, "."`

Comment: FWIW, :scip, :none is gone from cap 3: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/777

Answer (score 8):

The `deploy_via, :copy` has been dropped in version 3.

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/695

In most cases you should have your code in a online repository like github or bitbucket, and then you just have to set this line in your deploy.rb file:

```
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:my_account/my_project.git'
```

Though if you happen to have a repository on the remote server that you are deploying too, then you would change that line in your deploy.rb file to be this:

```
set :repo_url, 'file:///home/deploy/bare_repo/my_project.git'
```

Keep in mind that the three forward slashes are important since the `file://` tells capistrano that you are looking for a file, and the preceding slash is needed to point to a root path which would be something like `/home/deploy/bare_repo/my_project.git`.

Answer (score 7):

```
set :repository, 'file:///path/to/your/git_repository'
set :local_repository, "file://."
set :scm, :git
# set :deploy_via, :copy # you must comment it
```

Answer (score 7):

Capistrano 3 solution which is running for me:

```
  before :deploy, :deploy_from_local_repo

  task :deploy_from_local_repo do
    set :repo_url,  "file:///tmp/.git"
    run_locally do
      execute "tar -zcvf /tmp/repo.tgz .git"
    end
    on roles(:all) do
      upload! '/tmp/repo.tgz', '/tmp/repo.tgz'
      execute 'tar -zxvf /tmp/repo.tgz -C /tmp'
    end
  end
```

Before deploying you are uploading a tar.gz file to the server, unzip and finally reset the :repo_url to file mode.

Take care to remove the pervious repo:

```
task :remove_repo do
  on roles(:all) do
    execute "rm -r #{repo_path}"
  end
end
```

Comment: This works for me, except I was getting an error `refs/stash does not point to a valid object!` until I changed the tar command to `tar -zcvf /tmp/repo.tgz --exclude=.git/refs/stash .git`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I used a combination of @Ariejan and @HungYuHei answers which worked for me.

```
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :use_sudo, false    
set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "."
set :local_repository, "."
set :branch, "master"
```

If you use local copy (and don't have the project on Github), then it is also wise to disable `:check_revision` task in your deploy.rb which checks whether remote is in sync with local git.

Comment: I get the following `fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.`

Answer (score 0):

normally deploy via copy is super slow.
but copy_cache only available if scm is NOT none (sync uses scm)
this means that deploy from working copy can only be done with sluggish copy.
I managed to find a fast setup for copy deploy from local repo that is fast.
You still need to locally commit changes though but do not need to push them.

```
set :scm, "git"
set :local_repository, "file://."
set :deploy_via, :copy
# cache only seems to work if use scm
set :copy_cache, true
set :copy_via, :scp
set :copy_exclude, [".zeus*", ".bundle", ".git", "tmp/*", "doc", "log/*", "fixtures/*"]
```

Unfortunately it sometimes breaks mysteriously with:

```
fatal: Could not parse object 'c438b9d1242cb311be43d681e3f89bc486d748ed'.`
```

Ideally syncing local cache should be implemented even if no scm is used for deploy from working copy to work. great feature to add to capistrano