# usually with Capistrano deployed Rails app has to be deployed by hand due to port restrictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

due to problems with the IT services on my clients site I have to deploy by hand to our ubuntu host system. We usually deploy our rails apps on the clients system with Capistrano. Since the installation of a new firewall and the incompetence to open more than port 80 within the next 5 days I need to deploy a rails app by hand..

And honestly I have no clue how to do that.

I can access the host with admin rights via ssh, and I'm also able to scp my code.

My plan would be to replace the code within the "site/current" folder with my code from my master branch. So I replace everything beside the shared folders with my code and hope it works...

I'll run the rake tasks, restarting bluepill, sidekiq, reindexing elasticsearch and so on by hand.

Is there a config file by Capistrano or anything else I'll have to change beside the database.yml?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Kind regards
Oliver

Comment: Capistrano only need ssh access to the server and you have this access - are you using different port?

Comment: I'm connecting to the server via VPN, so I can connect via ssh. The problem is that the host cannot connect to github to pull my repository because port 22 and 423 are not opened from the host machine. If you know any way to route/proxy this request over the ssh connection to my machine and from there to github this would also help.

Comment: You can use capistrano to copy the code from your local copy directly to the machine if the server has no access to github.

Comment: I followed Jons hint and deployed by the copy function of Capistrano, see my own Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed Jons hint and solved my problem by creating a new capistrano task with following variables:

```
task :acceptance_test_trial do
  #new copy variables
  set :scm, :none
  set :repository, "."
  set :deploy_via, :copy
  set :local_repository, "file://."

  server "xxxxxxxx", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
  set :deploy_to, "/var/www/sites/xxxxxx.local"
  set :user, "deploy"
  set :rails_env, "acceptance_test"
end
```

This stackoverflow conversation helped me [How to Configure Capistrano to Deploy from Local Git Repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532323/how-to-configure-capistrano-to-deploy-from-local-git-repository)